# JavaScript toggle button not changing state on document.load

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, onload

I want to create some toggle buttons. But in the following code, according to me, the starting value of button two is 'true' and on document.load it should change automatically. But when running, it does not change the button state.
Actually, all this HTML file will be used in a C++ program as a string where buttons' starting values will be retrieved from a server.

Here goes my code.
If you want to suggest new logic please do. :-)

```js
var st = [false, false, false];
document.onload = function WL(a) {
    st = [false, true, false]
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        oof(i);
    }
};

function oof(a) {

    p = document.getElementById(a);
    cv = p.value;


    if (st[a] == false) {
        cv = p.value = p.innerHTML = "On";
        p.style.backgroundColor = "#4CAF50";
        st[a] = true;
        //  prc(a);
    } else if (st[a] == true) {
        cv = p.value = p.innerHTML = "Off";

        p.style.backgroundColor = "#f44336";
        st[a] = false;
        //  prc(a);
    }
}


function prc(b) {
    r = "?p=" + b;
    var a = document.createElement("form");
    a.setAttribute("method", "post");
    a.setAttribute("action", r);
    a.style.display = "hidden";
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.submit()
};
```

```css
.b{background-color:#f44336;border:0;color:white;padding:15px 32px;text-align:center;display:inline-block;font-size:16px;margin:10px 0 10px 0; width: 100%; height: 200px}

.b:hover{background-color:#4caf50;}
.b:active{background-color:#008cba;}
```

```html
<button class=b value=Off id=0 onclick="oof('0')">Off</button> <br />
<button class=b value=Off id=1 onclick="oof('1')">Off</button> <br />
<button class=b value=Off id=2 onclick="oof('2')">Off</button>
```

Comment: Replace `document.onload` by `window.onload` and you'll solve your problem.

Comment: Got it. thanks. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a simple test:

```
<html>
<head>
 <script>
  document.onload = console.log
 </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

And I found, that `document.onload` never fires. However, `window.onload` as well as `document.body.onload` works.

That said, you are best off using `addEventListener` instead which is best practise:

```
<html>
<head>
 <script>
  window.addEventListener('load', console.log)
 </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `load` did not work, I gave a try to `DOMContentLoaded` and it works perfectly. anyways, thanks for the idea. :-) cheers.

Comment: Actually I tried the code you which I posted and it worked as expected. However, DOMContentLoaded is the better event anyway for your usecase

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 problems with your code:

1. Try to use `window.onload` instead of `document.onload`
2. You should not use `;` between `for` statement and the code block that you want to be executed in loop.

So, the line:

`for (i = 0; i < 3; i++); {`

should be:

`for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {`